# aapt error on android

Tags: android

When I have an layout test.xml file open and click on Run Android creates an empty test.out.xml file and creates an "Unparsed appt error".

Even when I delete the newly created file the "Unparsed appt error" doesn't disappear.
What happens here?
How can I fix the error? Is there a way to prevent this from happen when I accidentally click on run while in a .xml file instead of being in a .java file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you run Project/Clean, the error will go away.

Regarding preventing this from happening, you have to change the build action for XML. I have not spent the time figuring out how to do that, but since this is such an annoying thing, I'd be glad if someone could post the steps.